# Is Zookeeper Essential For XD Single Node?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, spring-xd

This question relates to the XD 1.1.2.RELEASE.  I'm brand new to XD, so please forgive if this is a dumb question.

The documentation says only that XD does not ship with Zookeeper, and I took this to mean that it would only be needed once I'm ready to go multi-node.

That being said, I'm getting some undesired behavior in trying to deploy a stream:
1.  Any time I add a stream, it is not persistent across XD restarts.
2.  The stream setup is timing out.  In debug mode, it's getting stuck in ModuleDeploymentWriter in spring-dirt.  If I'm reading that class correctly, it seems like it's writing a file to be read by Zookeeper and then timing out when a response is never received.

At first I thought it was my custom Cassandra XD sink connection that was timing out, but it doesn't seem like that code is ever reached in the first place.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The documentation says only that XD does not ship with Zookeeper, and I took this to mean that it would only be needed once I'm ready to go multi-node.

That's right. But, XD single-node uses embedded ZooKeeper.

> 1. Any time I add a stream, it is not persistent across XD restarts.

Are you using singlenode or distributed mode? If you are using singlenode, everytime XD restarts it uses different ZooKeeper instance. Hence, in singlenode, you can't get the streams persisted between server restart. You can still override this functionality by providing external ZK configuration for single-node by setting `zk.client.connect` in servers.yml.

> 2. The stream setup is timing out.

Some log messages or stack trace could help figure out what's going on here. If you are using single-node, the ModuleDeploymentWriter should write the deployment to the container that's running on the same JVM.

In case if you are running on the debug mode like @dturanski mentioned, you can try increasing deployment timeout property `xd.admin.deploymentTimeout` in servers.yml. The default is 30s.

Comment: I've upped the timeout to 3000s, and still it times out.  I wish there were some useful log messages or a stack trace but I'm getting nothing here.

I'm running single-mode.  It sounds like maybe I should run Zk anyway, but meanwhile I'm mystified as to what the module stream writer is waiting for.

Comment: hmm, at what line the ModuleDeploymentWriter is stuck?

Comment: It's stuck on 471, at the wait().  The immediate reason it is stuck is because addResult() is not being called in time for the timeout.  The crazy thing is though, that eventually addResult _is_ called.  The longer I set my timeout, the longer it takes for addResult to be copied.  I now have stream deployment timeout set to about an hour, and that just seems to slow down the process.  There's got to be something else I'm missing, I'm tearing my hair out here.  I did eventually install Zk and it's working fine.

Comment: The ModuleDeploymentWriter uses ResultCollector which is a CuratorWatch. It is set on `module deployments status path` in ZK for each module in the stream. This status path (with status either deployed or failed) would eventually be updated by the container when it deploys the module or times out. In your case, there seems to some issues with embedded ZK that the singlenode uses. You can check if the ZK paths are correctly set on the embedded ZK. The single-node server startup would show the embedded ZK connect URL at the log.

Comment: I'm no longer using embedded ZK but still facing similar issues.  Standalone ZK is creating the "xd" path and even deploying my custom modules.  According to ZK standalone, my source and sink modules are getting deployed but not the stream.  And there is almost nothing useful in the log.

Comment: >  According to ZK standalone, my source and sink modules are getting deployed but not the stream. And there is almost nothing useful in the log.     - I don't understand what do you mean by your modules are deployed but not the stream. Stream will have the overall deployment status for the modules it hold. Do you mean the stream status isn't updated? and, for the log, you don't find anything useful even after activating `DEBUG` log? I thought the debug log would at least list all the deployment steps.

Comment: After turning on DEBUG, still no.  I see a lot of these:

Comment: `2015-05-15 18:14:34,234 1.1.2.RELEASE DEBUG DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 xml.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
2015-05-15 18:14:34,235 1.1.2.RELEASE DEBUG DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 xml.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
`

Comment: `2015-05-15 18:14:34,239 1.1.2.RELEASE DEBUG DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be trav
ersable.`

Comment: But since nothing I am using uses JPA, I'm not entirely certain why xd chooses to tell me this about 20 times.  After a flurry of log messages, there's just no further activity in the log at all.

Comment: Finally, I'm not sure what to make of what ZK is showing me.  Maybe I was misreading it before.  I'm brand new to that tech also.  Here's status:

Comment: `get /xd/deployments/streams/arf2/status{"state":"deploying"}
cZxid = 0xfe
ctime = Fri May 15 18:14:33 UTC 2015
mZxid = 0xfe
mtime = Fri May 15 18:14:33 UTC 2015
pZxid = 0xfe
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x14d5765bf900007
dataLength = 21
numChildren = 0`

Comment: ok, yeah, the stream status is set to `deploying` and there are issues when the corresponding modules getting deployed to the container. what do the shell commands `stream list` and `runtime modules` show?

Comment: stream list shows that my attempts at streams are "deploying", at least until my one hour timeout is reached.  Then it says they have "failed".  Runtime modules shows an empty list.

Comment: ok, the longer timeout doesn't make sense unless you are debugging and you need some time. Typically, if the ZK is up then you should get it deployed pretty quickly. The longer timeout (5s) is set to use in large cluster and also to allow all the containers to respond if you have more modules in a given stream. In your case, the deployment fails because of the timeout and I believe 5s should be good enough in this case as well. Did you try a simple stream like "time | log". If you are deploying a custom module, check if there are something wrong with the module itself.

Comment: Huh.  "time | log" deployed about instantly.  I do have a custom module I created (cassandra, as it happens) but in my last tests I was trying for something simple by just specifying "http --port=9020 | log".  The rest of the http module should be right out of the  box and the only thing I'm adding is that port.  Could that be screwing things up somehow?

Comment: And now, after a restart, everything (including new "time | log" streams) are ALL getting stuck in "deploying" status.

Comment: It is weird that you don't see any logs on the deployment failures. It is expected to have some logs on failed deployments with the reason why it fails on the container log. Since, the basic streams aren't getting deployed I suspect something weird in your environment. As an alternative, can you try running distributed mode? or, Can you open a JIRA or github issue with all the log information you have.

Comment: I can try that, but I'm hoping that wouldn't be necessary.  This is a brand new GCE instance with nothing on it that I didn't put there ... and so far I've only added java 8, xd, and zookeeper.

Comment: It is worth checking if there could be hostname resolution issue on the container application on the singlenode. You can see what IP address/hostname is assigned to container when you start xd-singlenode. If you are running everything on localhost, may be you can try setting these environment properties: XD_CONTAINER_IP and XD_CONTAINER_HOSTNAME to be 'localhost' and see if that works

Comment: I think I figured it out.  You were right, it is an environmental issue.  I had been running xd in bash as a background job, which was fine except that my only option to shut it down was using bash kill.  I think this screwed something up.  Running as a foreground process in a devoted terminal, and shutting down with Ctrl-C, removing all my streams and adding from scratch, has seemed to have solved these issues.  Thanks a lot for your patience and willingness to stick around with suggestions!  I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: No problem, I am glad it worked finally :-) . Feel free to ask any questions related to Spring XD here or JIRA/Github.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need external Zookeeper to run in singlenode since it starts an embedded server. This keeps state in memory, so you lose state between restarts. However, you can configure it to connect to an external Zookeeper ensemble.

If "debug modue" refers to running SingleNodeApplication with a debugger, then yes it could time out if you set a breakpoint.